# How to create a project in GCP via java SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a project in GCP via java sdks but it throws me an exception that I do not hold enough permission to create one.

```
PrivateKey privateKey = privateKeyFromPkcs8(privateKeyPem);
GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setServiceAccountId("")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Lists.newArrayList("")) // discussion on scopes
        .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
        .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(privateKey)
        .build();

CloudResourceManager cloudResourceManager = new CloudResourceManager
        .Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), googleCredential)
        .setApplicationName("")
        .build();


ResourceId resourceId = new ResourceId().setId("").setType("");
Project requestBody = new Project()
        .setName("")
        .setProjectId("")
        .setParent(resourceId);
Operation response2 = cloudResourceManager
        .projects()
        .create(requestBody)
        .execute();
```

"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "The caller does not have permission",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ]

I am able to fetch the list of projects but not able to create one.

Comment: Make sure that the service account you are using has project creator role.

Comment: Having project creator and billing admin at org level for SA should take care of permission issues.

Comment: Please could you confirm that adding the [project creator role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resourcemanager.projectCreator) and [billing admin](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#billing.admin) role to the used service account fixed your issue?

Comment: yet it has solved my issue.

Comment: @Kampassi would you mind listing the imports? there are duplicate names all across google packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have [Project Creator Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resourcemanager.projectCreator) and [Billing Admin Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#billing.admin) in the used service account in order to be able to create a new project.